# hadoop2.7.2:cannot find java

Tags: java, hadoop, centos7

I am using Hadoop 2.7.2 and CentOS7.

When I try to run this in the terminal it gives me this error:

```
/usr/hadoop/bin/hdfs:line304: 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java: no such file or directory
```

When I `echo $JAVA_HOME`:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

In `/etc/profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
export CLASSPATH=.：$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
```

How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jimmy, welcome to Stack Overflow. I just wanted to give you a quick tip. the `` characters are great for including code inside of a line like `here`. But, to give the gray background to more than one line of code, you should indent each line with 4 spaces (and the lines that need to be indented more, just add to the 4).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason by myself.

Actually, `java-1.8.0-openjdk` is the built-in `jre` environment in CentOS7, not the `jdk` environment at all. I renamed it from `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0b14.el7.xl7_2.x86_64` for simplicity.

The original `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0b14.el7.xl7_2.x86_64` is `jre` not `jdk`. So, just set up the `jdk` environment.